# Creating actorRefs from ACtorSystem using DI() Extension, throws object reference exception

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, akka.net

I am trying to setup a base project that will make use of Autofac for dependency injection.

I have the following problem, when trying to get an instance of my Actor doing the following:

```
_system = Akka.Actor.ActorSystem.Create(_settings.SystemName);
PingActor = _system.ActorOf(_system.DI().Props<PingActor>(), ActorNames.PingActor);
```

This throws an 'Object reference' exception.  The PingActor is null.

Below is how I am loading my modules in my setup, and registering the Actor Instance.

Static class that contains a helper to help setup my Autofac setup.

```
public static class IoC
{
    public static IContainer Container { get; set; }

    public static void Bootstrapping(Action<ContainerBuilder> builderConfig)
    {
        //new builder instance
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builderConfig.Invoke(builder);
        Container = builder.Build();

        builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.ScanAssembly();

        builder.Update(Container);
    }
}
```

Here is the `ScanAssembly` extension method:

```
public static class ContainerBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void ScanAssembly(this ContainerBuilder builder, string searchPattern = "Template.*.dll")
    {
        var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        foreach (var assembly in Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern).Select(Assembly.LoadFrom))
        {
            builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assembly);
        }
    }
}
```

Where I try to register my Actor:

```
public class IoCModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<ActorSystemShell>().As<IActorSystemShell>();
        builder.RegisterType<PingActor>();
    }
}
```

Why am I getting my Actor as Null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing the AutoFacDependencyResolver.

I modified my code to look as follow:

```
public void Start()
{
    _system = Akka.Actor.ActorSystem.Create(_settings.SystemName);

    // Create the dependency resolver
    IDependencyResolver resolver = new AutoFacDependencyResolver(IoC.Container, _system);

    PingActor = _system.ActorOf(_system.DI().Props<PingActor>(), ActorNames.PingActor);

    Console.WriteLine($"Starting actor system: {_settings.SystemName}");
}
```